# spectrum theory in generalized cohomology

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, spectra

why  is  generalized  cohomology  theory  equivalent  to  spectrum  theory ?  specifically,  why is that  any generalized cohomology theory is represented  by  a spectrum and  a  spectrum gives  a generalized  cohomology  theory?

Comment: Well, it is a loooooong story.  Step 1 is to understand the representability of $H^n(-;A)$ by $[-, K(A,n)]$.

Comment: @Randall, Can you  elaborate  more? thx

Comment: I cannot (in comments).  It's an elaborate story that took me several grad courses to learn.  But, reading up on my Step 1 really is the first step toward understanding this.

Comment: can  you give me a reference?

Comment: I've always liked Switzer's book.  He gets to this story about halfway through.